# Universal link common to both Full App and AppClip

Tags: ios-universal-links, apple-appclips, universal-link

I want to use universal link common to both Full App and AppClip ex: https://example.com, and the desired scenario is as follows:
  1. When users install AppClip, scan this link will show AppClip Card
  2. When users install Full App, scan this link will show Full App

- This is the content in the file https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association I have installed:

```
`{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "teamId.xxx.yyy.Example",
            "paths": ["*"]
        }]
    },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["teamId.xxx.yyy.Example.Clip"]
    }
}
`
```

- Here is the Associated Domains setting on the Xcode side:

  ```
  Full App: applinks:example.com

  AppClip: appclips:example.com
  ```

But the results are not as expected, when scanning the link, it always shows the AppClip Card with the message: "This app clip is not currently available in your country or region" (even when I don't have AppClip installed), and Every time you test the main app, you will have to use “Clear Experience Cache”
Please help, thanks a lot.